# How to solve this fetch data problem in Vue.js 3 and Cordova

Tags: php, android, mysql, vue.js, cordova

I have created an application that fetches data from my MySQL database through a PHP API.

When I tried to build a debug APK, it was successful. but the problem was, when I installed it the fetching of data in my database is not working anymore. So I used different android version and luckily it's working. My android version was 10.

Do you guys have any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! So I understand your problem is solved, but you are looking for a reason why it did not work? Perhaps giving a [minimal-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can help someone to identify the problem.